# Watchkit dynamic notification button customization

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I'm looking to customize the dismiss button and the button I sent via the PushNotificationPayload.apns via "WatchKit Simulator Actions" in my dynamic notification. Can someone please show me what I am overlooking?

Also, how do I handle the functionality of pressing the button? Ideally I would like to send information back to the parent app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering first question: it's not possible to customize dismiss button nor buttons added via PushNotificationPayload.apns. They are provided by system.

Answering second question:
In your PushNotificationPayload.apns you have something like this:

```
"WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
    {
        "title": "Button 1",
        "identifier": "button1Action",
    },
    {
        "title": "Button 2",
        "identifier": "button2Action",
    }
],
```

Then in your main interface controller, implement this method

```
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification
{
    // Detect button identifier, decide which method to run
}
```

However, remember that on actual device if you plan to use LocalNotification you need to implement

```
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification;
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

And if you want to send data to iPhone app use

```
openParentApplication
```

method of InterfaceController class.

Answer (score 3):

in complement to lvp's answer i've detailed the procedure to register the new category in you're iphone parent app there :  (needs for production apns)

[How to Handle Action Buttons in Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484951/how-to-handle-action-buttons-in-push-notifications/29915455#29915455)

****EDIT****

in resume :

From the a Server APNS you have to send a category (for me Respond):

```
{"aps":{"alert":"bla","category":"respond","badge":2}}
```

Register for that Category in you're parent's app appDelegate :

```
     - (void)registerSettingsAndCategories {
// Create a mutable set to store the category definitions.
NSMutableSet* categories = [NSMutableSet set];

// Define the actions for a meeting invite notification.
UIMutableUserNotificationAction* acceptAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
acceptAction.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Repondre", @"Repondre commentaire");
acceptAction.identifier = @"respond";
acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground; //UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground if no need in foreground.
acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

// Create the category object and add it to the set.
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory* inviteCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
inviteCategory.identifier = @"respond";

[categories addObject:inviteCategory];

// Configure other actions and categories and add them to the set...

UIUserNotificationSettings* settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                        (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound)
                                                                         categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];}
```

And handle this in your WatchKit Extention :

```
  - (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier  forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification{

     if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"respond"]) {
        //Do stuff Here to handle action... 
     }}
```