# WatchKit Notification payload example

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

As you may know, on the PushNotificationPayload.aps file, actions can be set on the "WatchKit Simulator Actions" node.

Can someone provide me a real push notification payload that includes actions?

Thanks!

Comment: @Gavin, what's wrong with you? Why you -1 my question?

Comment: It's not good to make assumptions like that. I have not downvoted your question, somebody else did it.

Comment: @Gavin, Oh I'm sorry. Is there a way to know who did it? I'm new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Nope, no way to see who downvoted you. I only edited your question to fix a typo in your title. It would be very bad if you could see who upvotes or downvotes questions and answers, because it would lead to people retaliating against other people very likely.

Comment: Please look at my Answer below : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484951/how-to-handle-action-buttons-in-push-notifications/29915455#29915455

Comment: Please take a look to my previous answer Below : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484951/how-to-handle-action-buttons-in-push-notifications/29915455#29915455

Answer (score 1):

We use a test payload that looks something like this:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "My Alert Title",
            "body": "The body message",
        },
        "category": "myCategoryName"
    },

    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
           {
           "title": "Like it!",
           "identifier": "MY_LIKE_ACTION"
           }
    ],

    "myCategoryDictionary": {
        "image" : "http://.....",
        "subject" : "The subject of the alert message",
        "content": "Detailed content info can go here"
    },

    "customKey": "Use this file to define a testing payload for your notifications. The aps dictionary specifies the category, alert text and title. The WatchKit Simulator Actions array can provide info for one or more action buttons in addition to the standard Dismiss button. Any other top level keys are custom payload. If you have multiple such JSON files in your project, you'll be able to select them when choosing to debug the notification interface of your Watch App."
}
```

Comment: myCategoryDictionary not working in my code. I'm running on watchOS 2 simulator.