# "WatchKit Simulator Actions" not working on actual apple watch device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-watch

I've tested the simulated apple watch push notification and it works fine...

However when I tried to send it to the actual apple watch, the button doesn't appear... why is it so?

And it doesn't vibrate or beep when I send the push notification in json format instead of text...

```html
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "Great!\nNew input",
            "title": "Optional title"
        },
        "category": "sCategory"
    },
    
    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
                                   {
                                   "title": "Details",
                                   "identifier": "sDetailsButtonAction"
                                   }
                                   ],
    
    "customKey": "Use this file to define a testing payload for your notifications. The aps dictionary specifies the category, alert text and title. The WatchKit Simulator Actions array can provide info for one or more action buttons in addition to the standard Dismiss button. Any other top level keys are custom payload. If you have multiple such JSON files in your project, you'll be able to select them when choosing to debug the notification interface of your Watch App."
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW5).

To specify custom action buttons, you need to create a custom notification category. When you create the notification, set the category to your customized one.

The example from the Apple Documentation:

```
func registerSettingsAndCategories() {
    var categories = NSMutableSet()

    var acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    acceptAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Accept", comment: "Accept invitation")
    acceptAction.identifier = "accept"
    acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var declineAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    declineAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Decline", comment: "Decline invitation")
    declineAction.identifier = "decline"
    declineAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    declineAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var inviteCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()

    inviteCategory.setActions([acceptAction, declineAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    inviteCategory.identifier = "invitation"
    categories.addObject(inviteCategory)

// Configure other actions and categories and add them to the set...

    var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
```

Comment: where should I place this in? is it in      func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {?

Comment: I tried to send this json and also set the registerSettingsAndCategories when the app receive notification. But the button still doens't appear on the apple watch :  { "aps": { "badge": 1, "alert": "Your message", "sound": "cat.caf","category":"respond" } }

Comment: this belongs somewhere in the code you execute on startup (e.g. your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions). the
you can then, when you schedule a notification, set the category property of the notification to your custom category
there is a detailed tutorial on how to create custom notification actions (=buttons) [on this page](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/)

Comment: note, that apart from the simulator, you do NOT need any JSON. This is just the textual representation of a UILocalNotification Object.

Comment: got it! Placed it inside "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and it works!

Comment: @jannik-michel  woah... I'm a little late here but you said we don't need JSON? JSON is just to test the sim? So for real world we do all of this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like above?  So if I have a chat app on iOS that receives notifications should I be using local notifications or remote notifications to display notifications on WatchOS? Right now I am creating categories in the payload.apns file. Avatar would be `"img_url" : "exmaple.com/ssd.jpg"`, username would be `"sender" : "Kelvin"`, type would be `"type" : "Follower"`etc.  We don't do this real-world?

Comment: @TokyoToo: Not sure if you still need help on this, but yes, as I said, the JSON payload file is only for simulation purpose, in the running app, that load is abstracted/automatically generated by the aforementioned functions.

Answer (score 1):

From a previous awnser : [How to handle action buttons in push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484951/how-to-handle-action-buttons-in-push-notifications/29915455?noredirect=1#comment48733325_29915455)

1) Register for the category in your appDelegate's parent app :

```
- (void)registerSettingsAndCategories {
// Create a mutable set to store the category definitions.
NSMutableSet* categories = [NSMutableSet set];

// Define the actions for a meeting invite notification.
UIMutableUserNotificationAction* acceptAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
acceptAction.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Repondre", @"Repondre commentaire");
acceptAction.identifier = @"respond";
acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground; //UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground if no need in foreground.
acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

// Create the category object and add it to the set.
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory* inviteCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
inviteCategory.identifier = @"respond";

[categories addObject:inviteCategory];

// Configure other actions and categories and add them to the set...

UIUserNotificationSettings* settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                        (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound)
                                                                         categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];}
```

2) From your Apns server add the category (for me "respond")

```
{"aps":{"alert":"bla","category":"respond","badge":2}}
```

3) In your WatchKitExtention, you have the data passed in :

```
 - (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier  forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification{

     if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"respond"]) {
//Do stuff Here to handle action... 
     }}
```

4) In your Parent app's appDelegate :

```
- (void)       application:(UIApplication *)application
handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
     forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
         completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    completionHandler();
}
```

Warning ! you'll have to handle this action too in your Parent app ( because the respond button will be visible too on iphone when you pan down the notification. in the :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
```

Comment: Be aware, on actual device you'll have to send an real push notification for testing, you can't use the notification payload since it's gray in your scheme..